# How to get size of the windows console in python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, console

i need some program that get the current window size of the console

i tried below program

```
def get_windows_term_width():
    from ctypes import windll, create_string_buffer
    h = windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(-12)
    csbi = create_string_buffer(22)
    res = windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(h, csbi)
    if res:
       import struct
       (bufx, bufy, curx, cury, wattr,
       left, top, right, bottom, maxx, maxy) = struct.unpack("hhhhHhhhhhh", csbi.raw)
       sizex = right - left + 1
    else:
       sizex = 90
    return sizex
```

but i get default setting as the sizex=90 even if i change the settings in cmd.exe

Comment: Why you are using the `STD_ERROR_HANDLE` (-12) in the GetStdHandle function and not the `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` (-11)?

Comment: The code works for me as is, giving a size of 80 (using both `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` and `STD_ERROR_HANDLE`).

Comment: Your code works fine with Portable Python